# Schedule a DB job based on specific date

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

I have DB job and now I would like to run this job only on specific dates. dates could be in any month like first run on 15 May 2015 and next run woule be 20 July 2015 .. 11 OCT 2015 etc etc.

Through scheduler we dont see such fluxibility. I guess this can be done through some function and call that in scheduler.

Could someone please help me on that.

Answer (score 4):

Your task can be solved without using any additional functions, you can create a schedule with `FREQ=YEARLY` and with `BYDATE` clause you can specify an exact dates. For example:

```
BEGIN
 dbms_scheduler.create_schedule('my_sched', 
   repeat_interval => 'FREQ=YEARLY;BYDATE=0515,0720,1011');
END;
```

This plsql block will create the schedule named `my_sched` which contains 15 May, 20 July and 11 OCT of every year. You can use this schedule while creating your jobs.

You can read more about oracle calendaring syntax here:  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_sched.htm#BABEJGCH

Comment: Thanks for your post. Let me check this and I will get back to you in case of any issue.

Comment: One additional question on this, is there a way I can skip the scheduler run for a specific date/time ..? My scheduler is scheduled to run on every sunday 7 PM but for some specific date, I would like to skip that. pls suggest

Comment: Yes, actually, you can use an `EXCLUDE` clause to exclude some dates from your schedule. You can see a description of that clause by the link in my answer.

Comment: Extending your answer you can also add a hour and minute i.e.:
repeat_interval => 'FREQ=MONTHLY;BYMONTH=JUL;BYDATE=0707;BYHOUR=16;BYMINUTE=00'